# Looking for history on a theorem of clique intersections

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

I have a short paper I'm working on where I prove:

*Theorem:  Every graph on (2t-1) vertices with no (t+1)-clique has a vertex that is contained in every t-clique.*

By "t-clique", I mean a complete subgraph with t vertices.  It's actually a lemma for the main result in the paper, but it's where most of the work is done.  It feels like something that has been done before, but I haven't come up with anything in my searches. I think it might be related to clique graphs or clique-helly graphs, but I haven't found a direct link.

Does anyone know of a paper with this result?  Or another result that would imply this one?  Or at least a related paper that might be worth looking into?  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hajnal's Clique Collection Lemma implies your theorem. See Corollary 2.10 from this paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.4564v5.pdf or Hajnal's original paper http://cms.math.ca/cjm/v17/cjm1965v17.0720-0724.pdf .

Comment: So much for that paper I was working on.  But thanks --  That's exactly the sort of thing I thought might be out there, and very quick response too.

Comment: +1ed.  Welcome to MO!  I am glad you exist now.